# Find the first occurrence of a pattern match in a file and then stop traversing the data

Tags: python, regex, file

I have a file having such data

```
D11/22/1984 D 123 q423 ooo 11/22/1987
R11/22/1985 123 q423 ooo 11/22/1987
D12/24/1986 123 q423 ooo 11/22/1987
511/27/1987 123 q423 ooo 11/22/1987
D18/29/1988 123 q423 ooo 11/22/1987
```

I need to pick the first occurrence of a record matching the pattern `^D(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})` and then break and stop traversing through rest of the file.

For example in the data mentioned above I just want to pick the value `D11/22/1984` and not `D12/24/1986` or `D18/29/1988`.

I want to write it in Python using the `re` module.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a generator over your file-obj (the following assumes it's called `f`) which applies your `re.match`, then take the first occurrence of a match, eg:

```
matches = (re.match('D(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})', line) for line in f)
first_match = next((match.group(1) for match in matches if match), None)
```

If you get `None`, then no matches were found. You can also extend this to easily take `n` many matches:

```
from itertools import islice, ifilter
first5 = list(islice(ifilter(None, matches), 5))
```

If you then get an empty list, no matches were found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function that iterates over the file object with a for-loop and the returns when it finds the first match:

```
import re
def func():
    with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f: # Open the file (auto-close it too)
        for line in f: # Go through the lines one at a time
            m = re.match('D(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})', line) # Check each line
            if m: # If we have a match...
                return m.group(1) # ...return the value
```

Iterating over a file object yields its lines one-by-one.  So, we only check as many lines as necessary.

Also, I removed the `^` from your pattern since `re.match` already matches from the start of the string by default.

---

If you already have a file object open, just remove the with-statement and pass the file as an argument to the function:

```
import re
def func(f):
    for line in f: # Go through the lines one at a time
        m = re.match('D(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})', line) # Check each line
        if m: # If we have a match...
            return m.group(1) # ...return the value
```

Just remember to close the file when you are done with it.

Comment: Thanks...can I do it without opening the file ?

Comment: You mean you want to use an already open file object?  Sure, see my edit.

Comment: Happy to have been of help! Please do not forget to accept an answer by clicking the check next to it. Doing so lets people know that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

you could consume the rest of your data like so

```
^D(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})[\s\S]+
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/147)

Answer (score 1):

This regex captures only the first occurrence:

```
import re

filedata = '''
D11/22/1984 D 123 q423 ooo 11/22/1987
R11/22/1985 123 q423 ooo 11/22/1987
D12/24/1986 123 q423 ooo 11/22/1987
511/27/1987 123 q423 ooo 11/22/1987
D18/29/1988 123 q423 ooo 11/22/1987 
'''

print(list(re.findall(r'^D(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})?.*', filedata, flags=re.M|re.S)))
# ['12/24/1986']
```

Furthermore, re.search scans the string and returns only the first occurrence found and stops scanning (maybe this is what you are looking for):

```
print(re.search(r'^D(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})', filedata, flags=re.M|re.S).groups())
# ('11/22/1984',)
# no need of the (...)?.* Your original pattern can be used.
```

With this regex, findall finds... all occurrences:

```
print(list(re.findall(r'^D(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})', filedata, flags=re.M|re.S)))
# ['11/22/1984', '12/24/1986', '18/29/1988']
```

Comment: for 
print(re.search(r'^D(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})', filedata, flags=re.M|re.S).groups())
 can I enter file path in filedata ?so that I can parse thorugh the file till the first occurance , without opening it

Comment: It has to be a string, not a file object.